# Angular - is this another way to write an initializer function?

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-ui-angular2

See this link, included StackBlitz link there, as I couldnt link directly to it.
https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/editing/editing-row-click/

In this Kendo UI Angular example, a grid is setup for in-line editing.  I'm curious about how they defined the fromgroup outside of the main class definition.  Is this just another way to define an "initalizer" method?  What would be another way to write this, putting it inside the class itself as a method?

```
const createFormGroup = dataItem => new FormGroup({
    'Discontinued': new FormControl(dataItem.Discontinued),
    'ProductID': new FormControl(dataItem.ProductID),
    'ProductName': new FormControl(dataItem.ProductName, Validators.required),
    //'UnitPrice': new FormControl(dataItem.UnitPrice),
    'UnitsInStock': new FormControl(dataItem.UnitsInStock, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[0-9]{1,3}')]))
});
```

Comment: Depends on what do you mean by "different". `FormBuilder` certainly helps making such functions more concise and readable. https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Comment: By "different", I mean without using a constant.  For example, if you look at the linked example, there is a method in the class that references createFromGroup like this  this.formGroup = createFormGroup(dataItem);  Seems like one could just as easily create a method that accepts a dataItem and returns a FormGroup?

Comment: `formGroup()` is just a function that accepts `dataItem` and builds a `FormGroup` around it. Considering that it doesn't refer to any particular `this`, actually it looks like a pure function, there's really no difference what way it's declared: a class method, a static method, an arrow function, a `function` function, if it's declared in the same file or refactored into some `helper.ts` file (with the necessary imports like `FormControl` and `Validators`) and imported from there.